# Are there tools to extract name/value pairs from an HTML dropdown list when it is dynamically populated?

Tags: html, html-select

I would like to extract the name/value pairs available in the dropdown controls listed on this website: http://www.dotmed.com/listings/postlisting.html?type=equipment&mode=sale

The initial list is static, so this is easily to do. However, the rest seem to be populated dynamically. What would be the easiest way to extract these name/value pairs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dynamically loaded boxes are called by an ajax query.
Here is the header request sent when you click one.

```
http://www.dotmed.com/ajax/components/ajax

POST /ajax/components/ajax HTTP/1.1
Host: www.dotmed.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0
Accept: text/javascript, text/html, application/xml, text/xml, */*
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
X-Prototype-Version: 1.6.0.3
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Referer: http://www.dotmed.com/listings/postlisting.html?type=equipment&mode=sale
Content-Length: 96
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
_comp=%2Fajax%2Fcomponents%2Flistings%2Fshow_categories&_t=equipment&form=select_form&_h=28&_c=2
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 29 Mar 2013 19:59:47 GMT
Server: Apache
Connection: close
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

The line you're interested in is

```
_comp=%2Fajax%2Fcomponents%2Flistings%2Fshow_categories&_t=equipment&form=select_form&_h=28&_c=2
```

_h= contains the option value that you selected.
_c= contains, i suppose, the box that needs to be populated

So, if you want to get the list of items for the second box for the selection "Cosmetic", you'd grab the id (30) and change _h.

If you want the data for the third box for cosmetic->chiller,  You would change _h to 2738 and _c to 3

Basically, you just need to see what you're sending to the server when you're clicking it and then send it a bunch of requests for everything else.

Comment: Thanks. I used Wireshark and was able to see the AJAX queries.

Comment: Awesome.  If you use firefox, I'd recommend the live http headers plugin and the tamper data plugin.  That will help you out as well.